springdoc-openapi v2.6.0 Not Exposing Swagger-UI
I'm using the following versions:
    spring-boot-starter-parent: 3.3.3
    java.version: 21
    spring-cloud-version: 2023.0.3
    springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui: 2.6.0 

When I run the application and try to access /swagger-ui/index.html, I receive a JSON response instead of the Swagger UI.
{"name":"swagger-ui","profiles":["index.html"],"label":null,"version":"d2592f45c32657d214294f6b030bef6003d0ee6d","state":null,"propertySources":[]}

And here is an example of my REST endpoint:
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/test/api/web-client")
public class WebClientResource {

    @GetMapping("/greet")
    public String greet() {
        return "Hello World!";
    }
}

And here are used dependencies in pom.xml
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-starter-webmvc-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


I have problems too:
"Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'GET' is not supported]" and Method Not Allowed 405 when I tried to open 'swagger-ui/index.html' page.

springdoc.api-docs.path=/v3/api-docs
springdoc.swagger-ui.path=/swagger-ui.html

Add these in your application.properties  and also check if your application under Spring Security,Please allow the path in Configuration like these:
http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**", "/v3/api-docs/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated();

